# Pig documentation for MR jobs

Tags: apache-pig

Does anyone know any Apache pig documentation which list down all the operators (like group by, streaming, etc) and the corresponding action taken by PIG i.e what kind/count of MR job(s) the operator results in?

I am specifically interested in streaming aspect, how does it maps to MR job(s).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

However far not a complete list, but I think it's worth reading the following articles/sections:

Building a High-Level Dataflow System on top of Map-Reduce: The Pig Experience
(Section 4. Compilation to MapReduce)
http://infolab.stanford.edu/~olston/publications/vldb09.pdf

Pig Latin: A Not-So-Foreign Language for Data Processing
(Chapter 4.2 Map-Reduce Plan Compilation)
http://infolab.stanford.edu/~olston/publications/sigmod08.pdf

Furthermore you can always issue [EXPLAIN](http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.10.0/test.html#explain) or [ILLUSTRATE](http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.10.0/test.html#illustrate) on your script
to see what happens behind the scenes.